# How to make a frozen set in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a set of values that I don't want to be editable, like this:

```js
// I don't want this to be editable.
const listenedKeys = new Set(['w', 'a', 's', 'd'])

// This should be fine.
const hasA = listenedKeys.has('a')

// I want this to give an error.
listenedKeys.add('r')
```

**Can I "freeze" this set in TypeScript? How?**

I've tried using the [`Readonly` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype), but that doesn't prevent me from modifying the set:

```js
const listenedKeys: Readonly<Set<string>> = new Set(['w', 'a', 's', 'd'])

// No error here
listenedKeys.add('r')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript already supports this type natively. It is called `ReadonlySet` and will do exactly what you want - you will not be allowed to modify the set once created

```typescript
const listenedKeys: ReadonlySet<string> = readOnlySet(new Set(['w', 'a', 's', 'd']))
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQEwewOwOQBdQHcCGcVIBYEsBnUJGUAIwFNQKo8l0yAbCgOgCgBjeAlRwpCnBoBpCgE8CALlAAlCulhxGYgMoUkAHh4AnPHADmAPlABeUENSg1SABQBtBKgQAaUAnQu3BTwigIAugCUbGwgoAAq+EQEODAAroxQ5FQAZnqsnNwo6AAK2hQEBDSmoHw8giLiBCw46AQ27gjBoWCQGFjEUcSk+ngAblSY1NraMNrsZQJCUKISLApQDdpNIWHojASkFCNjUmyTFTNVLFAUzAINTsEH07PVHMzo2jaBQA)

If you want to use implicit typing, you can create a small helper function that will serve only to switch the types:

```typescript
const readonlySet = <T>(set: Set<T>): ReadonlySet<T> => set;

const listenedKeys = readonlySet(new Set(['w', 'a', 's', 'd']))
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsFMIZVABwDYEMCeBzATgewK4B2AJqAC7bSpkDOoqom0h02AlgMagDubZkoXC3rZM+ALbMy9OmwBmoPgHI6AKTgANAHQQYoDrnHiGAK3w1pAI3SJUNGtDr82NLQCgDhC6EqpiQ5HQ4aGkAXlAAHnAAGlAAPgAKBzIALlBgsii4gEo0gCUqf0JAjKzQULjQZIBuNzcQUABJUCKlaW5UQmlnJ1xQS1hoYj5US2Rod09vZBcyZiGAaWh0OnDfIpKQhJZudK2AbSVuJVilVBPQFQulYiUAXWzsuoaoFyrIAmRSAdA5NhZJkJvKgAAqUexDcqgGYWebEJYrLSQOwJM5KJ71MDNDpdciQN5kPqYNgAN1gnVArDw2HcMLmLHhy1cfmIqOw6OeYFQyBofSpuGwNBSbjpcIRrmI0HGc1RxyeooZ4q0HHGqGwCWyQA)

The type is defined in [the es2015.collection.d.ts file](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es2015.collection.d.ts) alongside analogous types `ReadonlyMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own interface by inherit like:

```
interface FrozenSet<T> extends Set<T> {
  add: never,
}

class FrozenSet<T> extends Set<T> implements FrozenSet<T> {}

const listenedKeys = new FrozenSet(['w', 'a', 's', 'd'])

// @ts-expect-error
listenedKeys.add('r')
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGJQPYC8IgMoRgA8AKgHzIQAekIAJgM7IHHnIDeAsAFDLJx06ALmQgIAN2gAaHgF8ePBABs4DJumy4WpCtVqNmhHcmABbAA5KIp3GHWYc+I23bzuijCAZhkS4N9wIOgBpCABPJgBeUQgAdzQHLUIACgBtAHJY9KlkdLhs3IYC9Lp0gF0ASgVuAHoa5AABOwBaanMIBDBWqEwoHj8AsRDwhgA6ATpk9Kh0iqA)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new type which will omit the `add` property and prevent it from being used on the `listenedKeys` variable:

```
type MyNewSet = Omit<Set<string>, 'add'>;

const listenedKeys: MyNewSet = new Set(['w', 'a', 's', 'd'])

const aPressed = listenedKeys.has('a')

listenedKeys.add('r') // error
```

Here is a link to the playground:
[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiByEDuBlCwoF4oHkC2AlsADxokDOwATgQHYDmAfADRQDkAhgCZduMDcAKEEB6EVACSULgHtabDEg60MwABYFyUYDKgAjaBC5EOegDYQAdIIDGcylDObgEWkYDSEEOQBcsBMhkWFBuSFBkABQA2mxIbKyc8ezkSWy8ALoAlMJiUAAqGlrkajIArmZc%20tAAZnRWtvYYHAAKVBDk5EbBTpSuHl7klmoc5BGJ2aLiUkoq2oXauvQEAG7QylAQVFQyVNY9Lm5cnt6W3FxjVGyZQA)